# Converting ASP T-SQL IIF statement to MySQL

Tags: mysql

In the table tblmap, I have columns mapelec, mappaper and mapplan.  In these columns I have the words TRUE or FALSE.  I am new to MySQL and have these T-SQL statements I am trying to convert to MYSQL statements:

```
IIf([tblmap].[mapelec],'Digital Maps'

IIf([tblmap].[mappaper],'Paper Maps','Other Maps')) AS MapType
```

To convert to MySQL I am guessing this is what it means:

```
CASE WHEN tblmap.mapelec = 'TRUE' THEN 'Digital Maps' WHEN tblmap.mappaper = 'TRUE' THEN 'Paper Maps' ELSE 'Other Maps' END AS MapType
```

Next:

```
IIf(([tblMap]![MapPlan]=True),'Plan View','') AS MapPlan
```

CASE WHEN tblmap.mapelec = 'FALSE' THEN 'Plan View' END AS MapPlan

Then this

```
IIf([tblmap].[mapelec],1)

IIf([tblmap].[mappaper],2,3)
```

CASE WHEN tblmap.mapelec = 'TRUE' THEN '1' END,

CASE WHEN tblmap.mappaper = 'TRUE' THEN '2' ELSE '3' END

I am making the assumption that [tblmap].[mapelec] is some kind of shorthand and means if the data in tblmap.mapelec evaluates as TRUE then do something.  Can someone tell me if I am converting these correctly?

Comment: You can (and should) test it yourself by comparing the ms sql server query results with the mysql one.

Comment: This is the third [same or similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74603776/how-to-convert-and-asp-sql-iif-statement-with-multiple-conditions-to-mysql) question you've asked - Are you asking us to test your own code?

Comment: No.  I haven't gotten an answer yet.  I am looking for an interpretation of the IIF statement so I can create the matching MySQL one.  No one has given me one.  I can test the code if I know what the above code means.  I have tried to remove irrelevant data and add more relevant data.  I have deleted one of the posts.

Comment: So have you not tested with using MySql's `IF()` expression?

Comment: Since I don't know exactly what this  IIf([tblmap].[mapelec],'Digital Maps'  or any of those other one's mean then no.  From what I read, I think I am supposed to use CASE and not IF() anyway.  But then again I don't know because I don't know exactly what those statements are doing.

Comment: tbh since t-sql doesn't evaluate boolean expressions like that neither do I. Does the existing code even work. The MySql IF works the same as IIF though - both are an inline-if and both are just syntactic sugar for a case expression.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out using my assumptions in my post.

```
IIf([tblmap].[mapelec],'Digital Maps'
IIf([tblmap].[mappaper],'Paper Maps','Other Maps')) AS MapType
```

Translated to

```
CASE
    WHEN tblmap.mapelec = 'TRUE' THEN 'Digital Maps'
    WHEN tblmap.mappaper = 'TRUE' THEN 'Paper Maps'
    ELSE 'Other Maps'
END AS MapType
```

I made all my IIF statements follow this format and I eventually returned the same results as the original T-SQL statements.